# About proving that $x_0$ is a minimum of a functional.

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm trying to prove that this function:

$$R[x]= \int_{0}^{1} (x'^2(t)+4x(t))\, dt$$

defined as: $R:X\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $X = \{x\in C^1[0,1],\mathbb{R}|x(0)=0,x(1)=1\}$ has a minimum at $x_0 = t^2$.

But I don't know how to do it properly. I've tried to use the Euler-Lagrange equation, but it doesn't seem to work.

Another way I've found is to use a theorem that states for a strictly convex funtion (which I've already proved that it is), if for $x_0$, the first order variation $\delta R(x-x_0)=0$ equals to cero, then $x_0$, is the only minimum of $R[x]$.  But I'm confused because the definition for the first order variation states that: $$\delta R(x_0,h)=\lim_{x \to{0}}(\frac{R(x_0+\lambda h)-R(x_0)}{\lambda})$$

But for $\delta R(x-x_0)=0$, where do I substitute that value$(x-x_0)$ in the first order variation? How can I solve it? I'm confused with the algebra, please, help. Does anybody knows a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use E-L equations
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial x'}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=0
$$
which in this case give you the ODE
$$
2x''(t)-4=0.
$$
The general solution is then
$$
x(t)=t^2+Ct+D
$$
The given boundary conditions force $D=0$ and $1+C+D=1$ that is $C=D=0$. Summing up, the only critical point is
$$
x(t)=t^2.
$$